# SQL Query in R for new Dates

Tags: sql, r, date, stored-procedures

Currently I have the following SQL stored procedure/query in R which works fine.

```
Factors<- data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn,"EXEC [Published_EquitySelfService].[usp_FactorTEContribution] 20171130, NULL, NULL"))
```

I want to define the date outside the stored procedure as such however I am getting an unexpected symbol error?

```
Date<-'20171130'
 Factors<- data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn,"EXEC [Published_EquitySelfService].[usp_FactorTEContribution]" Date", NULL, NULL"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `paste` to build the string to be executed:

```
Date <- '20171130'
cmd <- paste0("EXEC [Published_EquitySelfService].[usp_FactorTEContribution] ", Date, ", NULL, NULL")
Factors <- data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, cmd))
```

Note that most of the time it is generally bad to build SQL commands through concatenation, due to things like SQL injection.  But calling a proc from R console using this method may not fall into this category.

Comment: @user8491385 Sorry, typo.  Use `Factors <- data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, cmd))`